# How can I catch all 500 and above errors in DRF and log them?

Tags: django, exception, logging, django-rest-framework, middleware

I've looked through much of the SO responses regarding implementing this but I can't seem to find something that isn't deprecated or one that actually works for my use case.

Basically, I have some API methods that return their own status codes. However, if for any reason there is a 500 Server Error or anything above 500 which indicates something strange happened (for example lets say the database connection got timeout), I want that to be logged to a file or e-mailed to an admin.

I have tried using a custom exception handler but not all 500 errors are exceptions.

So I resorted to writing custom middleware, which looked something like this

```
class CustomApiLoggingMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if response.path.startswith('/api/'):
            ...do stuff here
```

The issue, however, is that there doesn't seem to be a `status_code`. To be frank I don't really know which response I'm actually getting. There's the 500 response returned by my API intentionally as a result of the API method, and there's the 500 response generated by Django in the backend if some kind of condition isn't met (let's say they sent a request without a proper header)

I tried to generate a 500 response / error intentionally by returning `Response(status=status.HTTP_500)` in some basic `/500` route. Even though this triggers the middleware, there is no `status_code` that I can use to check whether the response is actually a 500 or not.

I'm not even sure I'm doing this right, but hopefully you understand my intention. I would basically like to blanket catch all uncaught exceptions that can happen as a result of my API calls and log them or send them to an admin. Most calls that return some 40X or whatever are handled in the way that I want already.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Comment: I'd look into https://sentry.io in this case, you'll get better error logs and it integrates with everything pretty easily.  Not shilling, but have been using it for 5 years or more and wouldn't live without it.  All our dajngo projects, webapps, and even some command line tools use it.  Worth the 30/month easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely familiar with `MiddlewareMixin`, but the straightforward implementation with a callable class as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) seems to work:

```py
class ResponseStatusMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        print(f"Response has status {response.status_code}")

        return response
```

This works fine when the view does `return HttpResponse(status=500)` with the standard Django `HttpResponse`. However, when the view raises an exception, the middleware might be bypassed due to Django Rest Framework's exception handling. If `get_response` is raising an exception, you can handle it by implementing the `process_exception` hook in your middleware:

```py
class ResponseStatusMiddleware:
    ...
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        ...log your exception...
```

You could also convert uncaught exceptions to response objects with a custom handler, or, if possible, convert them to DRF's `APIException`, which is handled automatically.

Also, the `status.HTTP_500` should probably be `status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` (see [the DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/#server-error-5xx)).